# DataStax Cassandra cannot find Logback-Classic

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, sbt, logback

I am currently trying out the gigantic key-value store Cassandra in combination with a few other libraries such as Akka. After setting up a Cluster and connecting to a keyspace:

```
val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build()
self ! AddKeySpaceSession(keySpace, cluster.connect(keySpace))
```

I get the infamous "can't find the StaticLoggerBinder" warning message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further 
details.
```

Now usually, of course, you would simply place one (and only one) of `slf4j-nop.jar`, `slf4j-simple.jar`, `slf4j-log4j12.jar`, `slf4j-jdk14.jar` or `logback-classic.jar` on the class path. This is what I have done as is evident here:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaVersion = "2.5.8"
  val akkaDeps = Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion
  )

  val logbackVersion = "1.2.3"
  val loggingDeps = Seq(
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackVersion % Test
  )

  val cassandraDriverVersion = "3.3.2"
  val cassandraDeps = Seq(
    "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % cassandraDriverVersion
  )
```

Though the issue remains and Cassandra is actually the only one that complains about it.

Comment: 1. The `sbt` config seems to be cut off in the middle - do you actually return `loggingDeps` from this block? 2. The `logback-classic` dependency is in the `Test` scope - you might want to change that.

Comment: Oh wow i'm a blind idiot haha. Second point fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: We've all been there :-) I've posted an answer reflecting this for future generations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be related to the [scope](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html#Scoping+by+the+configuration+axis) of the `logback-classic` dependency. Instead of putting it in the `Test` scope:

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackVersion % Test
```

Try putting it under the default scope:

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackVersion
```